# Chroot Risks w/ /dev and /proc

Tags: linux, security, devices, chroot, proc

I am planning to set up a few chroot jails for some users to run/test Java applications (lets just assume each application is untrusted). Is there any risk involved with mounting /dev and /proc into each jail? If there is, what steps can be taken to get rid of this risk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exposing `/proc` and `/dev` exposes some more information and grants more rights to the users inside the jail.

Beware that uids and gids may be different inside and outside the jail. For instance, inside the jail, user "x" may be member of group 123, which in the jail is for "users" while on the system is for "disk". By bind-mounting `/dev`, you would grant them access to raw disk devices which would allow them virtually root access and get out of the jail.

I would not bind-mount /dev. Only create a few devices in there that the java application may need (`null`, `tty`, `zero`...) with the proper ownership and rights.

Have you considered linux containers instead of chroot jails which would isolate them more (lxcs are just a step further to chroot jails).

Comment: All of the answers were really informative. I've chosen this one because it was the most complete answer and warned me about the different uid/gid issue. Thanks sch

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a big subject, and quite a lot has been written about it on the web, so I'd encourage you to read around a little.

The basic summary is that chroot was never designed as a security feature. There are many ways a root user can 'escape' a chroot jail, and quite a few ways a normal user can escape. For example, the chroot does not have a separate process space, so a process within the chroot can 'attach' to any external process using the normal debug mechanisms. Some modern distros have protection enabled that would foil that particular attack, but not all. In any case, a root user is immune to almost all such protection devices, and there's nothing to stop it mounting any file-system it chooses.

LXC is better, and is also built-in to many modern distros (I believe) but suffers from some of the same issues (in particular, the /sys filesystem is open to abuse).

OpenVZ is supposedly safer, but it's a lot harder to set up, and I've not tried it myself.